# How to set a footer with transparency in Android

Tags: android, layout, transparency

All I want to do is to set a footer on my app.
What I have now is something like this:

[What I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG3ED.png)

Its just a XML with a ImageView under a List View.

And what I want is that:

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrNv6.png)

My image already have transparency... The problem should be that I dont know a way to "Get a view under a view"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) parent to contain both views.  Make the ListView fill the parent.  Make the ImageView anchor to the bottom of the parent with [layout_gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity)="bottom" and fill parent horizontally.

Make sure the ImageView is defined after the ListView so it will appear on top.

Answer (score 0):

If i get you right, you have an imageView with transparent background but the canvas that the image is painted on has a white background.

So basically you just need to make sure that in the image view you give add the image with "src:" property.

and for transparent background use:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```